# How to send a selected value of an option to a PHP function as a argument

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to send the value of selected index to a function, where all option values are coming through database.

```
<select onchange="get_api_key();" name="service">
    <option value="">Select your Service</option>
    <optgroup label="Apple Iphone">
        <option value="53">Apple </option>
        <option value="72">Ipad </option>
        <option value="77">iPhone</option>
        <option value="24">Iphone</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: You can't use a javascript variable inside a PHP function. However, you can use Ajax to change a javascript variable to a PHP variable and then use it for your purpose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

     var selVal = $('select[name="service"]').val();

     // send selVal as a PHP variable using Ajax
     $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:'getvalue.php',
         data:'selVal='+selVal,
         success:function(data){
               //do something if you want to with returned data
         }
     });    

});
</script>
```

Then in getvalue.php page,

```
$val = $_POST['selVal'];
// proceed to use $val for whatever purpose you want in this page
```

Comment: i want to pass this value to a php function and i am not able to this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

for the selected index use this.selectedIndex instead of this.value

see http://jsfiddle.net/corinnekm/FZY2v/2/